# How to connect to Database using Robot framework

Tags: python, selenium, db2, robotframework

If anyone knows, how to connect to the Database(db2) using using RobotFrame work.
I want to query database to verify the results.

any Idea would be appreciated !

Br

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. If you have working python code to connect to the database, just write a library for robot framework on top of it.
2. Of course, there is [A Database Library Already](http://franz-see.github.com/Robotframework-Database-Library/), maybe it can meet your requirements, or you'd have to go back to plan 1.

Good luck.

Comment: I have already downloaded [DataBaseLIb6](https://github.com/franz-see/Robotframework-Database-Library/archives/0.2) do I also need [MYSql-python](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python). once I get databaseLib6 and pySql-python, what to do next?

Comment: I have already downloaded [DataBaseLIb6](https://github.com/franz-see/Robotframework-Database-Library/archives/0.2) do I also need [DB2](http://wiki.python.org/moin/DB2). once I get databaseLib6 and DB2, what to do next?

Comment: The library mentioned earlier doesn't deal with the actual communication with the database, it works as an adapter between robotframework and the DB. You need to first make sure your python code can access the database -- install MySQL/DB2/Oracle if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Please install DatabaseLibrary into you machine and install it.
Make sure that pymysql is already available into your system, if not then please install it also.

Please follow the keywords given [here](http://franz-see.github.com/Robotframework-Database-Library/api/0.5/DatabaseLibrary.html).

Here I have written one successful rf script through which you can connect to your database:

```
***Settings*** 
Library  DatabaseLibrary
***Testcases***
TestCase

   Connect To Database Using Custom Params  pymssql  'DatabaseName', 'UserName', 'Password', 'ip address of the machine where this database is installed'
   @{S}  Execute Sql String  select * from TableName;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pymysql.cursors

def Delete_Fund(Name):
connection = pymysql.connect(host='ip',
                         user='root',
                         password='mysql',
                         port=3306,
                         database='novobank_auto',
                         cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        sql1 = "SET @fundName = '" + fundName + "';"
        cursor.execute(sql1)
        sql2 = "DELETE FROM `m_fund` WHERE `name` = @fundName;"
        cursor.execute(sql2)
        connection.commit()
        print("Fund : "+fundName+" has been Deleted")
finally:
    connection.close()

Delete_Fund("Name")
```

Answer (score -1):

For any database we need to establish the connection first and than execute the queries.

We have to follow 2 steps as below:-

1. Connecting to database need to install the database library (which contain the default keywords.
2. Install drivers lets say SQL drivers or Mysql drivers.

After the installation include the databaselibrary in robot framework and use the keywords provided by this library example like

**Connect To Database   pymssql ${dbName}   ${dbUsername}   ${dbPassword}   ${dbHost}**

[Complete step by step instructions to connect database with robot framework](http://www.ufthelp.com/2016/09/how-to-connect-robot-framework-to.html)